# Date popup field won't display in tableselect element

Tags: 7, forms, datetime

I am attempting to embed a couple of date fields within a `tableselect` element, and after trying to use both `textfield` and `date_popup` field types, I can't get either to work. Here's my form function using textfields:

```
function language_dashboard_overview_form($form, &$form_state, $entity) {
  $form = [];
  $options = [];

  $header = [
    'language_locale' => t('Language Locale'),
    'status' => t('Status'),
    'staging_url' => t('Staging URL'),
    'start_date' => t('Start Date'),
    'end_date' => t('End Date'),
    'display_title' => t('Display Title')
  ];

  $translations = $entity->translations->data;

  foreach($translations as $locale => $locale_data) {
    // Get data for all the other fields here
    ...
    // Define start and end date text fields.
    $start_date = new DateTime($entity->field_locale_publishing_dates[$locale][0]['value']);
    $new_start_date = $start_date->format('m-d-Y');

    $end_date = new DateTime($entity->field_locale_publishing_dates[$locale][0]['value2']);
    $new_end_date = $end_date->format('m-d-Y');

    $start_date_field = [
      'data' => [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => 10,
        '#maxlength' => 10,
        '#default_value' => $new_start_date
      ]
    ];

    $end_date_field = [
      'data' => [
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#date_format' => 'm-d-Y',
        '#date_year_range' => '0:+20',
        '#default_value' => $new_end_date
        ]
    ];

    $options[] = [
      'language_locale' => $locale_link,
      'status' => $status,
      'staging_url' => $stage_url,
      'start_date' => $start_date_field,
      'end_date' => $end_date_field,
      'display_title' => $title
    ];

  }

  $form['dashboard'] = [
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options
  ];

  $form['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit')
  ];

  return $form;
}
```

With that, I get the fields, but no default value is filled in (and I've verified that the `$start_date_field` and `$end_date_field`  variables have the desired data).

If I try it with `date_popup` fields like so:

```
$start_date_field = [
  'data' => [
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'm-d-Y',
    '#date_year_range' => '0:+20',
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#default_value' => $new_start_date
  ]
];

$end_date_field = [
  'data' => [
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#default_value' => $new_end_date
  ]
];
```

I get no field at all in those columns. From the multiple items I've read on this, I'm adding the fields correctly to the `tableselect`. Is there something else I'm missing?

**UPDATE:** I discovered that for the text field, you use `#value` instead of `#default_value`. changing that shows my default date as desired. so the only remaining issue is that I can't get anything to show for a `date_popup` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't get the [date_popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/date/issues/3016484#comment-12879797) element to work in a tableselect element, so I ended up going with text field and the [jQuery_ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (included in core).

```
  $form['dates'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Set Dates'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE
  ];

  $form['dates']['start_date_popup'] = [
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => t('Start Date'),
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
    '#date_year_range' => '0:+20',
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#date_label_position' => 'none',
    '#id' => 'apply-start-date'
  ];

  $form['dates']['end_date_popup'] = [
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => t('End Date'),
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
    '#date_year_range' => '0:+20',
    '#date_label_position' => 'none',
    '#id' => 'apply-end-date'
  ];

  $form['dates']['apply_dates_button'] = [
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value'=> t('Apply Dates'),
    '#attributes' => array('id' => array('apply-dates')),
  ];

...

 'start_date' => array(
   'data'=> array(
     '#type'=>'textfield',
     '#value'=> $new_start_date,
     '#title' => 'Start Date',
     '#title_display'=>'invisible',
     '#name'=> 'start_date[' . $locale . ']',
     '#id'=>  'start-date[' . $locale . ']',
     '#attributes' => array('class' => array('datepicker')),
     '#size' => 10,
     '#maxlength' => 10
   ),
 ),
 'end_date' => array(
   'data'=> array(
     '#type'=>'textfield',
     '#value'=> $new_end_date,
     '#title' => 'End Date',
     '#title_display'=>'invisible',
     '#name'=> 'end_date[' . $locale . ']',
     '#id'=> 'end-date[' . $locale . ']',
     '#attributes' => array('class' => array('datepicker')),
     '#size' => 10,
     '#maxlength' => 10
   ),
 ),
```

and this JS behavior:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.dashboardDatepicker = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // Attach the datepicker to the selected fields.
      $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-30:+30',
        minDate: '-0',
        showButtonPanel: true
      });

      // Add click handler for apply button.
      $("#apply-dates", context).click(function(event) {
        // Keep the form from being submitted.
        event.preventDefault();
        // Get the dates from the fieldset
        var startDate = $("input[id*='apply-start-date']").val();
        var endDate = $("input[id*='apply-end-date']").val();
        // Get the set of selected checkboxes.
        if(startDate) {
          $("table#locale-table").find("tr.selected").find("input[id*='start-date']").val(startDate);
        }
        if (endDate) {
          $("table#locale-table").find("tr.selected").find("input[id*='end-date']").val(endDate);
        }
      })
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```